# Microbloging Module that saves as a node

Tags: 7

Does anyone have advice on a module that will save a user's posting as a Content Node Type? I would like to use something like Facebook-like status or Microblog but I'd like the user's post to be saved as a content node (and thus show up under the Organic Group's home tab). The other micro-bloging modules save to their own tables or to activity_log.

We're using Commons 2.10.

Comment: To be honest I'd just set up a 'microblog' content type, and create each of the list pages using [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) with contextual filters e.g. on user. The only tricky thing I can think of would be making nodes that are replies to other nodes... Could maybe be done using something based on Inline Entity Form or Relation. If there are other micro blogging features this doesn't cover it'd be useful to specify them in the question

Comment: I would think you could use a node reference field if it's a reply.  And if it's not set, it's a top level/parent.